# Inserting Hyperlinks in the new Google Sheets with App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

In the current version of Google Sheet, to insert a hyperlink in to a cell, you would do this

```
sheet.getRange(row, selectedColumn).setValue('=hyperlink("' + ontologyObject.accession + '";"' + ontologyObjectTerm + '")')
```

In the **new** version of Google Sheets, the hyperlink insertion is different, you do this.

```
sheet.getRange(row, selectedColumn).setValue('=HYPERLINK("' + ontologyObject.accession + '","' + ontologyObjectTerm + '")')
```

However, I have a problem in that the inserted value in the spreadsheet is not what I expect. In this image [showing the inserted link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa1UA.png), there is a ' inserted before the =HYPERLINK - I've no idea where this is coming from. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `setFormula` instead of `setValue`?

Comment: That worked. I would not have thought of that.

Comment: Ok, I'll make this a proper answer just so this entry is marked as answered appropriately.

Comment: Sorry it took me a few days to mark this as answered. I'm currently on holiday. Thanks again!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When setting formulas to a Sheet range you should always use [`setFormula`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula%28String%29) (or its variants) instead of `setValue`. Even though some formulas may work when using `setValue`, there's some quirks as you saw.