# Link to run script in sheet where it runs

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to make a variation on the send emails from spreadsheet tutorial, where users can put in unlimited emails to be sent to different recipients with different content, based on which row the information is in. I have code that parses a row and inputs the info in that row into the sendEmail() script method.

It would be most convenient for users if I could insert a link in a column in each row where they can simply click to activate the script. So overall my question is: How can I insert my script as a link in a cell in sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379645/inserting-hyperlinks-in-the-new-google-sheets-with-app-script) related to your question.

> In the current version of Google Sheet, to insert a hyperlink in to a
>   cell, you would do this
>
> ```
> sheet.getRange(row, selectedColumn).setValue('=hyperlink("' + ontologyObject.accession + '";"' + ontologyObjectTerm + '")')
> ```
>
> In the new version of Google Sheets, the hyperlink insertion is
>   different, you do this.
>
> ```
> sheet.getRange(row, selectedColumn).setValue('=HYPERLINK("' + ontologyObject.accession + '","' + ontologyObjectTerm + '")')
> ```

Using the code above, just change `setValue` to [`setFormula`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula%28String%29) base on the given [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22389978/8342742) from the post.

So your code will be like:

```
sheet.getRange(row, selectedColumn).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + ontologyObject.accession + '","' + ontologyObjectTerm + '")')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I just pate the url of the page where I edit the script, that can't be it? Is there a way to link directly to running the script?

As well, the script hasn't appeared in my add-ons tab in my toolbar. I tried looking through some help pages but honestly I can't figure out why it's not appearing. Do I have to authorize it somehow? I already authorized it to send email on my behalf...